# Regex find strings between colon

Tags: regex, graylog2

I try to regex the following string

```
 : hostname: Oct 16 03:49:39.515: %BLA: message
```

and want to get the strings between the ": " and the last string after the last ": "

when I use `: (.+?):` I get `hostname`.

Unfortenately I am not able to get `Oct 16 03:49:39.515`, `%BLA` and  `message`. I need single regex for every substring, I don't want to have them all in one.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I need one regex to find the substring between the second and third ": ", one for the substring between the third and 4. ": " and one for the substring behind the last ": "

Comment: @tpnx you mean this http://regex101.com/r/wT9qK8/2 ?

Comment: No, I need 4 regex "strings" where every regex represents one of your matches

Answer (score 3):

Since `graylog2` is written in Java I believe lookarounds should work. Try this regex:

```
(?<=: )(.+?)(?=: |$)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wT9qK8/1)

---

**Update:** If you really need 4 different regex for 4 components then use:

**RegEx 1:**

```
(?<=: )(.+)(?=(?:: .+){3}[^:]*$)
```

**RegEx 2:**

```
: [^:]*: (.+?)(?=: )
```

**RegEx 3:**

```
: [^:]*: .+?: ([^:]+)
```

**RegEx 4:**

```
(?<=: )([^:]+)$
```

Comment: great, but graylog only uses the first match. so I need one regex for every substring but I don't know how to "find" the second ": " to start there

Comment: Do you have a documentation of `graylog2 regex`. There should be some **global** switch or `findAll` type of feature.

Comment: I want to create 4 extractors, one for every substring, so I need 4 regex, one for every substring

Comment: But in question you wrote: `I need single regex`

Comment: I think its my bad english, I mean 1 (single) regex for every substring. My bad

Comment: You want to get `Oct 16 03:49:39.515` in one match but it also has colons in it.

Comment: What about `: .+?: (.+?):` etc.?